# Какой знак препинания поставить: запятую/тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Есть фраза: "Но как он там, один? Не пропадет ли?" 
Помогите, пожалуйста, мне нужно подчеркнуть, выделить слово "один". Именно оно ключевое. Какой знак лучше поставить: запятую или тире? Просто я не уверена, что вообще по правилам нужен знак препинания, чаще встречаю варианты без знака: "Но как он там один?" Но без знака фраза читается без паузы, без ударения на нужное слово. Как оформить предложение с нужной интонацией? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно выделить слово **один** , чтобы интонационное ударение падало на него, можно поставить перед ним запятую. **Но как он там, один?** Это запятая, на которую автор текста имеет право.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

В Нацкорпусе встречается много подобных выражений, но запятая нигде не ставится, например: Весь день на работе был как на иголках: **как он там один**? [Василий Вишневский. Как я выхаживал стрижа // «Наука и жизнь», 2009]

Рассмотрим предложенный вариант: **Но как он там, один? Не пропадет ли?**  При постановке запятой может измениться семантика предложения: **один ли он там (или нет)?**

Можно предложить такой вариант: Но **как** он там, **один**, н**е пропадет ли**? В этом случае ударение падает на вопросительное слово, на обособленное местоимение "один" и на глагол в конце вопросительного предложения.

Comment: _Sibylla: В Нацкорпусе встречается много подобных выражений, но запятая **нигде** не ставится_. === **Нигде?** См., к примеру, у Фадеева: _**«Как-то она там, одна?..**»_ [А. А. Фадеев. Молодая гвардия (1943-1951)] http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EA%E0%EA-%F2%EE+%EE%ED%E0+%F2%E0%EC+%EE%E4%ED%E0

Comment: Обратите внимание на "как-то". Здесь уже однозначный смысл.

Comment: Здесь два интересных интонационных варианта.  Но кАк он там, одИн?  На "как" делается повышение тона (вопрос) в обоих случаях, а вот на "один" можно понизить тон (это правильная по смыслу интонация) или повысить тон (это неправильная по смыслу интонация, она передает второй вопрос). Как читать - указать нельзя, вот и получаются два смысла.